# Killing processes within Runnables

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I am working on a Java program that opens multiple instances of a command line concurrently. To do this, I am using Threads with `Runnable`s as shown here:

```
//Handles the command line running
private Process p;
private String port;
private String path;

@Override
public void run() {
    ProcessBuilder pb = //Initialization of ProcessBuilder
    pb.directory(new File(this.path));

    ...

    try {
        p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor(); //Using this since the server must continue after it is started.
         ...         //This is the part I need to cancel when I close the thread.

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {          //These exceptions are thrown from the process inside the Runnable.
        ...
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ...
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    p.destroy();
}
```

And in my `Main` application class:

`ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();`

```
public void startServer(String port, String path) {
    //Instantiate my Runnable Class, with port and path parameters
    MyRunnable rss = new MyRunnable(port, path);

    //Spawn a new thread with the Runnable
    Thread thread = new Thread(rss);

    //Set the name of the thread (presumably for finding it later?)
    thread.setName("server-" + threads.size());

    //Start the thread.
    thread.start();

    //Add the thread to an ArrayList<Thread>?
    threads.add(thread);
}
```

So my question is: **How do I use my `stopServer()` method to stop the process from the Main class?**

Disclaimer: I'm very new to Multithreaded programming, so any help you can give would be awesome, there may be something simple that I simply do not know about how `Thread`s work.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `ArrayList<Thread>`, don't you instead want `ArrayList<MyRunnable>`??

Comment: This way, you can iterate through the list calling `stopServer()` if the object is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ArrayList<Thread>`, I'd instead use `ArrayList<MyRunnable>`.

This way, I could iterate through the list calling `stopServer()` if the object is not null.

Comment: So, I'm sorry, do I simply change the `ArrayList` to one of `MyRunnable` and then add the `MyRunnable rss` to that `ArrayList`? I just tried this leaving all other code the same and it still doesn't work. Do I need to modify something else as well? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisGilardi: You would change the generic type of the ArrayList and add your MyRunnable objects to it. I have no idea what you need to do with the rest of your code, since I'm not privy to it.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, Since I'm using JavaFX, I forgot that the `start()` method is not static, and was creating a new `Main` object. Since I was accessing the base `Main` object in my methods, it was not bringing up the correct `ArrayList`! DOH! But you have the correct answer, thank you!